# Using $broadcast inside $interval in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've search this site and googled but can't find an answer, I have one module for services and another one for the app itself, inside the services module I have:

```
$interval(function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('tick');
},1000);
```

and in the app section I have:

```
$scope.$on('tick'), function(event){
    alert('tick');
}
```

I took this model from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/ADukg/51/).
Apparently the 'tick is triggered as no error is shown on console, but the app code never executes...

Comment: It doesn't work because your code isn't valid, please run it through JSHint or JSLint before asking questions here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code provided is not valid, that is why the problem occurs. 

Comment: use a browser console to inspect errors before posting syntax problems!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24on): `$on(name, listener)`

Perhaps a copy paste related error, but you have defined your listener function outside the `$on` method, so it will never be called.

Move the right parentheses that is located just after `'tick'` and put it after the listener function definition and it should hopefully work:

```
$scope.$on('tick', function(event){
    alert('tick');
});
```